# CocoaHTTPServer on iOS: set up server so user can download NSData as file

Tags: ios, hyperlink, download, nsdata, cocoahttpserver

I want to make the following webpage using `CocoaHTTPServer`: there should be a link to download a file, but the source file must be `NSData` object in memory.

As far as I see in samples, there is an easy way to link some file on iPhone to the hyperlink. Is it possible to "link" `NSData`?

Would be very thankful for examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All you need to do is to return [`HTTPDataResponse`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Core/Responses/HTTPDataResponse.h) in your HTTPConnection subclass.**

If you want an example have a look at the CocoaHTTPServer sample called [`DynamicServer`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/blob/master/Samples/DynamicServer/MyHTTPConnection.m) and replace `- httpResponseForMethod: URI:` in `MyHTTPConnection` with something similar to the following:

```
- (NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path
{
    // Before returning you can analyze the passed path argument and select the correct data object to return...
    return [[HTTPDataResponse alloc] initWithData:placeYourDataInstanceHere];
}
```

Comment: Hah! So simple, how I missed it... Thanks!

Comment: How do you analyze the request data if it's a `POST` instead of a `GET`? For example, if `JSON` data is sent with the request.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are interested to know. The request method (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, ...) is send as the first argument `(NSString *)method` to the method.